# Get on a table with composite rowkey from HBase shell

Tags: hbase

For a table that has a composite row key of two integers, what should be the command to get a row from hbase shell.

I have created this sample ruby script

```rb
include Java
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

id   = ARGV[0]
sid  = ARGV[1]

byte [] rowkey = Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes(id.to_i),Bytes.toBytes(sid.to_i))
puts Bytes.toStringBinary (rowkey) 
....
....
....
```

The output I see when I call hbase org.jruby.Main script.rb 10 20
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14 which clearly show 16 bytes long. How do I ensure that it is 8 bytes long (4 for id, 4 for sid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `toBytes` is overloaded to accept both `long` and `int` arguments, and JRuby always converts `Fixnum` to `long`.  There is no way to choose the overload with the `int` argument.

Instead you must use an alternate way to create the array.  First initialize an empty array, and then add each ID:

```rb
rowkey = Java::byte[8].new
Bytes.putInt(rowkey, 0, id.to_i)
Bytes.putInt(rowkey, 4, sid.to_i)
```

Comment: One last clarification, i have added the following to .irbrc to be able to call from hbase shell                                     def pget(id,sid)
        rowkey = Java::byte[8].new
        Bytes.putInt(rowkey,0,id.to_i)
        Bytes.putInt(rowkey,4,sid.to_i)
        key = Bytes.toStringBinary(rowkey)
        get 'table',"#{key}"
}                                                                      when i give:> pget 10 20   from hbase shell, i dont get a result . however, giving get 'table',"\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x14" returns the row. Am i missing anything in the ruby script?